# How to conditionally specify C compiler defines in bazel?

Tags: build, bazel

I am trying to convert Makefile build into bazel, and need to reproduce the following condition to specify CPU capabilities defines for C code compilation:

```
HAVE_AVX2 := $(shell grep avx2 /proc/cpuinfo)
ifdef HAVE_AVX2
$(info Checking for AVX support... AVX and AVX2)
CFLAGS += -DRTE_MACHINE_CPUFLAG_AVX -DRTE_MACHINE_CPUFLAG_AVX2
else
HAVE_AVX := $(shell grep avx /proc/cpuinfo)
ifdef HAVE_AVX
$(info Checking for AVX support... AVX)
CFLAGS += -DRTE_MACHINE_CPUFLAG_AVX
else
$(info Checking for AVX support... no)
endif
endif
```

Is it possible to implement such conditional in bazel? From what I have found, `cc_library` has `defines` and `copts` where I could use a `select` function, but I cannot understand what kind of condition I can use inside of `select`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/general.html#config_setting.

Generally, you do something like

```
config_setting(
    name = "avx2",
    values = {
        "define": "avx2=yes"
    }
)
```

and the you can select on `:avx2` condition:

```
cc_library(...
   copts = select({":avx2":[...], ...})
```

and run bazel with

```
bazel build --define avx2=yes ...
```