# How to coexist 2 Imgui versions in bazel project?

Tags: compilation, bazel

I am a programmer in an auto-driving company. We use ImGui to draw HMI interface. ImGui's Docking branch is in BETA. We want to use the Docking branch in local testing, and released version branch in online.

We use bazel to build project. How to coexist 2 branches in our project and easy to switch? When compiling online version, type `bazel build all`. When compiling local testing version, type something like this `bazel build all --use_imgui_docking_branch`?

Can bazel achive this requirement?

Comment: I answer by myself. Use conditional compilation, config_settings + Select().  Like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48329366/how-to-conditionally-specify-c-compiler-defines-in-bazel. I will write detail after I try out.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out.

1. Add imgui_docking in WORKSPACE

```
http_archive(
    name = "imgui_docking",
    build_file = "@//:third_party/imgui_docking.BUILD",
    sha256 ="...",
    strip_prefix = "...",
    urls = [...],
)
```

2. Use select in cc_library

```
config_setting(
    name = "imgui_docking",
    values = {"define": "imgui=docking"},
)
cc_library(
    name = "...",
    srcs = [...],
    hdrs = [...],
    deps = [...]
    + select({
      "imgui_docking" : [ "@imgui_docking" ],
      "//conditions:default" : [ "@imgui" ]
    }),
    defines = select({
      "imgui_docking" : [ "IMGUI_DOCKING" ],
      "//conditions:default" : []
    }),
)
```

3. Use macro control include in header

```
#ifdef IMGUI_DOCKING
#include "imgui_docking/imgui.h"
#include "imgui_docking/imgui_internal.h"
#else
#include "imgui/imgui.h"
#include "imgui/imgui_internal.h"
#endif
```

4. When compiling add --define

```
--define docking=imgui
```